# How to set Local Time when creating lead through API

Tags: api, leads, datetime, ruby-on-rails, database.com

I have a rails app that needs to occasionally add leads to our salesforce account. I got it to work just fine using the databasedotcom gem. Just one thing isn't working correctly, when I add a lead this way, the Local Time field isn't set in Salesforce. It just says "Unknown".

Does anyone know how I set it? If I look at my lead in the rails console, it has fields like CreatedDate, LastModifiedDate, SystemModStamp, etc.

I'm happy to supply more information if needed, just ask.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no standard "Local Time" Field on the Lead object. It is likely that this is a custom field specific to your org.  You would need to find out the API name of the field, and update your rails app to include that data element as well.

Comment: Ah, you're right. Do you happen to know where in Salesforce I can find out how custom fields are defined?

Comment: You go to Setup > Customize > Lead  then, select the Fields link, the standard fields are at the top, and the custom are at the bottom